# Draw Lines from the origin of a coordinate system to specific points

Tags: vector, gnuplot, coordinates, points

I have data that have 3 points to display in a 3D coordinate system. I want a line between each point and the coordinate origin (0 0 0). How can I draw these lines not connecting the points with each other but only with the origin?

I'm not very into gnuplot yet: I'm using the following code to display my data:

```
splot "C:/a/Drehmatrizenxyz.txt" with lines
```

But this only connects the points, which is exactly what I do not want.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Data file contains six values for each line.  From origin is (0 0 0 x y z)

Example - plot vectors <-1,2,-4>, <-2,0,1> & <2,9,2>

file.dat:

0 0 0 -1 2 -4

0 0 0 -2 0 1

0 0 0 2 9 2

gnuplot> splot 'file.dat' with vectors

[vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnLfl.png)

Answer (score 0):

In case this is still of interest...
Please check the [gnuplot homepage](http://www.gnuplot.info) and basic gnuplot tutorials and in gnuplot console `help vectors` or in general `help <keyword>`.

**Code:**

```
### plot with vectors from origin
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  1
EOD

set view equal xyz
set view 56,48, 1.3
set xyplane relative 0

splot $Data u (0):(0):(0):1:2:3 w vectors 
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]